# Can I "get rid" of the `drop column` line in the pattern below?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

In (`geo`)`pandas`, I've several `join` lines with the foloowing programmatic pattern:

```
b = gpd.sjoin(b, d, op="within", how="inner")
b.drop(columns=["index_right"], inplace=True)

b = gpd.sjoin(b, z, op="within", how="inner")
b.drop(columns=["index_right"], inplace=True)

...
```

The `inner` `how` produces an `index_right`. Is there a way to `sjoin` as a one-liner (effectively `deleting` the second line of `each` join above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for that in `sjoin` itself, but you can do the one-liner by appending drop right to the sjoin.

```
b = gpd.sjoin(b, d, op="within", how="inner").drop(columns=["index_right"])
```